# How to upload image in custom bundle in shopware 6 backend?

Tags: bundle, shopware, shopware6

**I want to create events from backend, i am using swag-bundle for it.
My whole form is working except image upload.
How i can upload image from backend.**

This is the  component of shopware library used in backend. **Backend in shopware 6 uses vue.js**

```
<sw-upload-store-listener :uploadTag="bundle5.image" autoUpload></sw-upload-store-listener>
<sw-media-upload 
              :label="$t('swag-bundle5.detail.TitleLabel')" 
              variant="regular" 
              :uploadTag="bundle5.image"   
              defaultFolder="media" 
              :allowMultiSelect="false">
</sw-media-upload>
```

[image]

Comment: Please ask a proper question with all related information https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @ChristopherDosin what information you didn;t get from question ? please elaborate. Thanks!

Comment: According to your screenshot the image upload seems to work. Do you ask yourself why it doesnt get persistet?